# LDAP connector for auth0

Tags: ldap, auth0

Can I install the connector directly to the server, and not every user?

I read this guide - https://auth0.com/docs/connector but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you install it once on the server. There's no concept of installing for every user. Installation instructions are at: https://auth0.com/docs/connector/install

This page summarizes how the Connector works: https://auth0.com/docs/connector/overview